# Android - App Force Close occured if no network connection while fetching JSON data

Tags: android, json

I'm using an asynctask to fetch json data from the web in the background. this works well, however the app force closes when theres no network connection.

The following is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS = 0;
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS = 1;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        // Download JSON File   
        new DownloadJSONFileAsync().execute();

    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading.....");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading.....");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog; 
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Show All Content
    public void ShowAllContent()
    {
        // listView1
        final ListView lstView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
        lstView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this,MyArrList));

        // OnClick
        lstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
                String strImageName = MyArrList.get(position).get("ImageName").toString();
                String strImagePathFull = MyArrList.get(position).get("ImagePathFull").toString();

                new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute(strImageName,strImagePathFull); // Download file Full Photo
            }
        });
    }

    // Show Dialog Popup 
    public void showDialogPopup(String strImageName,Bitmap ImageFullPhoto)
    {

        final AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


          View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog,
                  (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
          ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

             try
             {
                image.setImageBitmap(ImageFullPhoto);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // When Error
                image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
             }

          imageDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);  
          imageDialog.setTitle("View : " + strImageName);
          imageDialog.setView(layout);
          imageDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }

          });

          imageDialog.create();
          imageDialog.show(); 

    }


    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myArrList) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            context = c;
            MyArr = myArrList;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return MyArr.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null); 
            }

            // ColImage
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 80;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 80;
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
             try
             {
                 imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)MyArr.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // When Error
                 imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
             }

            // ColImgID
            TextView txtImgID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgID);
            txtImgID.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            txtImgID.setText("ID : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageID").toString());

            // ColImgName
            TextView txtPicName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgName);
            txtPicName.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
            txtPicName.setText("Name : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageName").toString());    

            return convertView;

        }

    } 



    // Download JSON in Background
    public class DownloadJSONFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {       
            String url = "http://XXX.com.xxp";

            JSONArray data;
            try {
                data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

                MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
                HashMap<String, Object> map;

                for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    map.put("ImageID", (String)c.getString("ImageID"));
                    map.put("ImageName", (String)c.getString("ImageName"));

                    // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
                    map.put("ImagePathThum", (String)c.getString("ImagePath_Thumbnail"));
                    map.put("ImageThumBitmap", (Bitmap)loadBitmap(c.getString("ImagePath_Thumbnail")));

                    // Full (for View Popup)
                    map.put("ImagePathFull", (String)c.getString("ImagePath_FullPhoto"));

                    MyArrList.add(map);
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            ShowAllContent(); // When Finish Show Content
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
            removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
        }


    }

    // Download Full Photo in Background
    public class DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String strImageName = "";
        String ImageFullPhoto = "";

        Bitmap ImageFullBitmap = null;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            strImageName = params[0];
            ImageFullPhoto = params[1];

            ImageFullBitmap = (Bitmap)loadBitmap(ImageFullPhoto);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            showDialogPopup(strImageName,ImageFullBitmap); // When Finish Show Popup
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS);
            removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS);
        }


    }


    /*** Get JSON Code from URL ***/
    public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }


    /***** Get Image Resource from URL (Start) *****/
    private static final String TAG = "Image";
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            copy(in, out);
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize = 1;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
            closeStream(out);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

     private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

     private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
            out.write(b, 0, read);
        }
    }
     /***** Get Image Resource from URL (End) *****/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error in the logs when this happens - it will tell you why it's crashing

Comment: Yes, I will post it later. I hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can check network connectivity before getting data from server. I always do this:

```
private void getDataFromInternet() {

    if(InternetConnection.isConnectedToInternet(CurrentActivity.this))
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

And in my receiver class I implement that method:

```
public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Checking Internet Connection...");

        boolean found = false;

        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {             
                found = true;
                internetStatus = 0;
            }

            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo _3g  = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (wifi.isConnected())
                internetType = "WiFi";

            if (_3g.isConnected()) 
                internetType = "3G";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CheckConnectivity Exception", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        if(found)
            Log.i(TAG, "Internet Connection found.");
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "Internet Connection not found.");

        return found;
    }
```

Therefore, You are always aware of network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

**This will help you surely!!!**

```
 if (!isOnline())
    {
            return ctx.getString(R.string.check_wifi);
    }

    else
    {
    // your service call goes here
    }

    public static boolean isOnline()
     {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably crash with a NullPointerException:

In `getJSONUrl` you execute the request, which will throw an `IOException` if you're not connected. You catch that `IOException`, and do not rethrow it, meaning that `getJSONUrl()` will return `null`. You then continue to use that `null` in `new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));`, which will most likely throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank for your help. I am a new in Android development. Would you please give me the full updated code to compare and review? Thanks.